# MassTransit: Set topic name after bus has started when when using IBus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'd like to create temporary subscriptions and queues to an existing topic after the MassTransit bus has started.  I can get halfway there by using the following code:

```
  services.AddMassTransit(a =>
            {
                a.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, b) =>
                {
// !!! This is the code I want to remove and define later on
                    b.Message<MyMessageType>(x =>
                    {
                        // Override to use an existing topic
                        x.SetEntityName("my-existing-topic-name");
                    });
... later on


        var bus = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBus>();
        var handle = bus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(new TemporaryEndpointDefinition(), new DefaultEndpointNameFormatter(true), receiveEndpointConfigurator =>
        {

            receiveEndpointConfigurator.Handler<T>(async context =>
            {
                // This is the message handler I'd like to add after the bus is started.
            }

...
```

However, the problem with the above code is that I need to call the `x.SetEntityName` before the bus is started.  I actually need to configure it inside the ConnectReceiveEndpoint (or immediately before/after).

I've scoured the documentation, I've tried finding APIs that expose the Topology so that I can modify it.  I'm at a loss.  I found one stackoverflow question that suggested using `IBus.ConnectConsumer`, instead, but that seems to lead to a dead end.  I found an `IBus.ConnectHandler`, which looks promising, but I'm just guessing at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure topology once the bus has been started. Any changes to the topic configuration would need to happen *before* the bus is started.

The only other option is to provide your own `IEntityNameFormatter` which would be used any time a message type is formatted to an entity name.

Comment: Further on this point, there's no way to set the AutoDeleteOnIdle from within ConnectReceiveEndpoint, right, because the topology is already set?  Using TemporaryEndpointDefinition() sets AutoDeleteOnIdle to 5 minutes for any Queues it creates, but not for any subscriptions.  "Temporary" subscriptions use the values from the topology.